# Total sum of multiple columns MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Please help me to get sum ...

```
select SUM(free),SUM(Paid),SUM(Guest)
from food_regs
where start date= 'date' and end date ='date'
```

[image]

Comment: what is your expected output

Comment: What do you want to do exactly?

Answer (score 0):

From your question, I assume you need the sum of three fields of a particular date.

Then try the following query

```
select free+paid+guest from food_regs where start date= 'date' and end date ='date';
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want fix the date part of the query, like this:

```
select SUM(free),SUM(Paid),SUM(Guest)
from food_regs
where 'date' > '2018-11-11' and 'date' < '2019-01-14'
```

Or did you mean you want the total sum, like this:

```
select SUM(free)+SUM(Paid)+SUM(Guest)
from food_regs
where 'date' > '2018-11-11' and 'date' < '2019-01-14'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try below - using group by which will give you employee wise summed value of each field

```
select emp_name,SUM(free) as totalfree,SUM(Paid) as totalpaid,SUM(Guest) as totalguest
from food_regs 
where start `date`>= '2018-11-12' and end `date`<= '2019-01-14'
group by emp_name
```

Answer (score 0):

You want the sum of `Free`, `Paid` & `Guest` individually, that is present between `start_date` and `end_date`.
This is something you can try:

```
select emp_name,SUM(free) as totalfree,SUM(Paid) as totalpaid,SUM(Guest) as totalguest
from food_regs where
date_field BETWEEN 'start_date' AND 'end_date');
```